# Postgres "group by" self reflection function (returning an array of primary keys consumed by the aggregate)

Tags: postgresql-9.3

Performing a "group by" aggregation query is simple enough.  What I'm interested in is if there is a feature/shortcut in returning an array of primary keys that were included in the function of aggregate and append/include it the query results.

For example:

link to example on sqlfiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5900d3/1

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
      id serial NOT NULL,               -- unique key
      eloc int,                         -- location of event
      rperiod character varying(1),     -- reference period
      rdate timestamp with time zone,   -- reference date
      edur int,                         -- duration in seconds
      CONSTRAINT foo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );

INSERT INTO foo (id, eloc, rperiod, rdate, edur) VALUES 
    (1, 1, 'h', '2014-12-20 08:05:01', 123),
    (2, 2, 'h', '2014-12-20 13:45:25', 73),
    (3, 2, 'h', '2014-12-20 15:20:11', 91),
    (4, 1, 'h', '2014-12-21 13:45:01', 302),
    (5, 4, 'h', '2014-12-21 13:45:01', 45),
    (6, 2, 'h', '2014-12-21 13:45:01', 103),
    (7, 3, 'h', '2014-12-20 11:17:52', 33),
    (8, 1, 'h', '2014-12-21 13:45:01', 164),
    (9, 4, 'h', '2014-12-21 13:45:01', 234)
```

A basic group query looks like this...

```
SELECT eloc, rperiod, rdate::date, sum(edur) 
   FROM foo WHERE   
      rperiod =  'h' 
   GROUP BY
      eloc, rperiod, rdate::date 
   ORDER BY eloc, rdate
```

Here are the standard result:

```
1;"h";"2014-12-20";123
1;"h";"2014-12-21";466
2;"h";"2014-12-20";164
2;"h";"2014-12-21";103
3;"h";"2014-12-20";33
4;"h";"2014-12-21";279
```

Here is what I would like my query to return... (notice the additional field containing the array of primary keys):

```
1;"h";"2014-12-20";123;{1}
1;"h";"2014-12-21";466;{4, 8}
2;"h";"2014-12-20";164;{2, 3}
2;"h";"2014-12-21";103;{6}
3;"h";"2014-12-20";33;{7}
4;"h";"2014-12-21";279;{5, 9}
```

I pretty sure I can accomplish this by a table to itself and with very specific queries.  Any thoughts on how to do this more generically?  Is there some sort of feature of postgres that does this for us?

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty easy, just add a call to `array_agg`

```
SELECT eloc,
       rperiod,
       rdate::DATE,
       sum(edur),
       array_agg (id)
FROM foo
WHERE rperiod = 'h'
GROUP BY eloc, rperiod, rdate::DATE
ORDER BY eloc,rdate;
```

SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5900d3/2

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Funny - going back and looking at documentation it was right there!!!